# Invoice number having one added to it up to 10, then stopping

Tags: php, max

im having a strange problem, I am using the following script to pull the last invoice number from the database and then add a 1 to it, this works just fine......until you get to 10 invoices, then for some odd reason I just keep getting 10 as the invoice number over and over again.

```
      <?php 
    $sqlinv = <<<SQL
       SELECT MAX(invoiceID) AS maxId FROM `sales`
    SQL;
    if(!$resultinv = $db->query($sqlinv)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}

    while($rowinv = $resultinv->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $previousinvoiceID = $rowinv['maxId'];
    }
    $invoiceID = $previousinvoiceID +1; 
    echo $previousinvoiceID;
    echo $invoiceID;
    ?>
```

$previousinvoiceID echos out as 9
$invoiceID echos out as 10
If I delete a few records it works again just fine, but as soon as it gets to 10 it starts repeating 10 again, its as though it treats 9 as the highest number all the time.

Comment: check the length of the maxId column

Comment: What data type is invoiceId? Make sure it is a numeric type such as INT and not a string type such as (VAR)CHAR.

Comment: If you're dealing with sequential invoice numbering, the method you chose won't be accurate. You can't use PHP to find out what the last invoice was and then increase that number by 1. There could be 2 or more users dealing with accounts and selling, both can end up with the same number as next invoice number. As for why you're getting 10, post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sales`.

Comment: I would use auto incrementing numbers in the db, but the problem is I need to view the invoice number on screen before the form is posted.

Comment: You can't have that information. It's inaccurate. You can see *possible* invoice ID. Even using auto_increment doesn't guarantee numbers being sequential. Also, many countries require sequential numbers when printing receipts for invoices. The reason you can't see that number is because two people could be selling goods. Both see that the last invoice number was 9. Both will (correctly) calculate that they will get the 10. And when they submit - well, easy to see what happens.